# Правильно переделать PHP-проект

Tags: php, html, mysql

Я создал на практике простой проект на php, где в формах надо заполнять кулинарную базу данных и просматривать таблицы из этой базы, выглядит это как куча php файлов в одной папке. Мне сказали что так проекты не делают, что надо чтобы был какой-то файл .htaccess, все функции в одном файле, чтобы всё было аккуратно и т.д. Думаю знающим людям понятно как должно всё выглядеть и какую кашу сделал я.

Нужен пример создания web проекта по всем современным правилам.

Comment: «Все функции в одном файле» — это вам ересь сказали. Должна быть одна точка входа и разбор ссылки (aka роутинг) в самом php (таким образом получаем независимость от apache), а .htaccess должен только перенаправить все запросы в эту самую точку входа. В php-коде же должны быть каким-либо образом (например, MVC) разделены логика и представление (html-код) и всё это логически распихано по разным php-файлам, чтоб удобно было читать и редактировать. За ночь не переделаете. Подробности в гугле. Инструкций много.

Comment: У меня мелкий школьный проект. Ну представьте в delphi маленькая формочка с полями для заполнения/отображения простой базы данных, вот только это всё в web. Сказали за ночь как раз реально.

Comment: Такое реально сделать даже за час, но только если заранее научиться, причём научиться не за одну ночь :)

Comment: В гугле тонны информации, не знаю с какой стороны к этому даже подобраться, может есть какой-нибдуь шаблон с комментариями?

Comment: Любой фреймворк.

Comment: Как фреймворк поможет мне создать проект правильно?

Comment: У хороших фреймворков очень трудно создать проект неправильно — всё жёстко задано идеологией и структурой фреймворка. Надо лишь следовать его документации.

Comment: Вот что мне сейчас сделать, чтобы с помощью фреймворка переделать/создать заново маленький школьный проект?

Comment: Взять любой фреймворк и следовать его документации :) Но, боюсь, за ночь всё равно не успеете :)

Comment: "надо чтобы был какой-то файл .htaccess" актуально только для Apache. Если вы вооружитесь nginx+`php-fpm`, это тоже будет неверно. И вообще привязываться к конфигу вебсервера, как сказали выше, плохо (без явной необходимости).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю это спасет отца русской демократии:

[Организация пространства адресов страниц веб-сайта средствами PHP и MySQL/MariaDB](http://webew.ru/articles/5216.webew)

В статье излагается подход, при котором запросы к сайту обрабатываются централизованно (через один PHP-файл), а адреса и содержимое страниц хранятся в базе данных. При этом адрес страницы может быть динамическим, а содержимое — включать в себя метки для подстановки переменных. Странице также может быть назначен исполняемый PHP-код.

Comment: Спасибо, похоже на то, что мне нужно сделать!